# Get the reply of an outgoing message in the same row in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the incoming message for an outgoing message in the same row as response? So, the data looks like below:

```
user_id     message             type
1           What's your name?   outgoing
1           Nitin               incoming
1           What's your age?    outgoing
1           17                  incoming
2           What's your name?   outgoing
2           Aayush              incoming
2           What's your age?    outgoing
3           What's your name?   outgoing
4           What's your name?   outgoing
4           Shubham             incoming
4           What's your age?    outgoing
```

The output should look like:

```
user_id     message             type        reply
1           What's your name?   outgoing    Nitin
1           Nitin               incoming    
1           What's your age?    outgoing     17
1           17                  incoming    
2           What's your name?   outgoing    Aayush
2           Aayush              incoming    
2           What's your age?    outgoing    No-reply
3           What's your name?   outgoing    No-reply
4           What's your name?   outgoing    Shubham
4           Shubham             incoming    
4           What's your age?    outgoing    No-reply
```

The reply is an incoming message for an outgoing message for a user_id & if there is no reply for an outgoing message then the reply column should be filled by 'No-reply'. I have to do this in PSQL. I am currently able to do this in python after fetching data from DB.

Below is my current python code.

```
df['reply'] = np.where((df['user_id'] == df['user_id'].shift(-1)) 
                       & (df['type'].eq('Outgoing') & df['type'].shift(-1).eq('Incoming')), 
                       df['message'].shift(-1), 'No-reply')
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered*  sets.  You need an additional columns that shows the ordering.

Comment: Do you want a Python solution or an SQL solution?

Comment: I need a SQL solution

Comment: This question isn't answerable unless there is a column from which we can establish an order like a timestamp or auto-incrementing id. At that point it's trivial with the `LEAD()` window function.

Comment: yeah, there can be a column for message send, assume message_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that can be used to order the records (called `id`), you could use `lead()` as follows:

```
select
    t.*,
    case 
        when type = 'outgoing' 
            and lead(type) over(partition by user_id order by id) = 'incoming' 
            then lead(message) over(partition by user_id order by id) 
        when type = 'outgoing' then 'no reply'
    end reply
from mytable
```

This query checks if the current record has type outgoing and if the next one (for the same user) is  of type incoming: if both conditions are true, then it recovers the message on the next record and displays it as `reply`. If type is outgoing but the next message is not incoming, then it gives no reply. In other cases, nothing is printed.